Use of 'analyzing ' as participle or gerund
This is excerpt from a sentence in "Word power made easy by Norman lewis book" of session 1 page no.28.
"You are unable to realize that other people do not spend as much time and energy analyzing you as you think."
My question is —In above sentence whether 'analyzing' has been used as participle(verbal adjective) or gerund(verbal noun)?
I think it has been used as participle (verbal adjective) because it is describing the people who do not spend time.But I an not confirm.
Help to clear my doubt! Thank you

It's a present participle verb. We know it's a verb because it has a direct object ("you").

There are lots of questions "Is it a gerund or a particple"
The answer to all these questions is the same.  There is no answer, since gerunds and participles are different names for the same thing.
If you want to know about Anglo Saxon, in which there was a difference then the question is answerable.  But in modern English grammar these are just two different names for the same thing.
